# How do I populate many-to-many relationship with WTForms and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I am building an app in tornado using sqlalchemy and wtforms. I have two models Committee and Member having a many to many relationship. I am having trouble populating the form using the sqlalchemy model.

My models look like this

```
class Committee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'committee'

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Member(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'member'

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    phone = Column(String)
    committee = relationship("Committee",
                  secondary=member_committee_table,
                  backref="members")

#query wrapper used in wtforms
def get_members():
    #return m.Session.query(Member).all()
    return m.Session.query(Member)

class CommitteeForm(BaseForm):
    name = TextField('name', validators=[Required()])
    members = QuerySelectMultipleField(query_factory=get_members())
```

This gives me error telling "Query" object is not callable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get rid of the '()'.
it requires a method factory

```
members = QuerySelectMultipleField(query_factory=get_members)
```